# Why is Sai Baba worshipped on Thursdays in particular

Tags: sai

Why is Sai Baba worshipped on Thursdays in particular.

Comment: Hello, too broad means asking more than one question per post. Again you are asking three questions in this post. Please ask only one per a post.

Comment: It's okay to ask very closely related questions so that people can see what you are getting at, but these three are very distinct. Please create separate questions. For the third one, I found the answer immediately by googling "Om sai ram meaning" which shows little research effort on your part. Please don't take my matter-of-fact nature of speaking as hurtful criticism. Rather, I hope it helps you improve your questions and improve the community.

Comment: It is a fact though that Sai Baba's main worship day is Thursday.

Comment: You are asking many questions in one question. Please limit your questions or ask them separately.